# Authentication between trusted application and an API

Tags: security, authentication, authorization

The application set up

Application A : Third party, windows desktop application. This is the application users are required to log in to. Logins are managed/authenticated locally

Application B : Our application, a windows system tray application. This integrates with application A. extracts information and sends to Application C.

Application C : This is our API, which application B calls in to send data.

Currently users are required to create an account in application C using GUI and enter the user details in application B to proceed. However users are questioning the process as they fail to differentiate the ownership between application A and B since they are tightly coupled.

Given we can trust that if a user is logged in to application A, they are genuine, I want to come up with a solution where you does not require to create another login. This would be based on the trust between application B, C, and the ability to detect if a user is logged in to application A.

End result would be, if a user is logged in to application A, application B detects that and sends the user details, to application C. Given there is trust between B,C user will be not require to do any thing for the authentication between B and C. However C will use user logged in to A for authorization.

Any ideas how I can get this done? in the lines of token based or trusted application authentication...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends entirely on the interfaces that Application A exposes. If Application A has an API that can be queried for the authentication status, you can use that API to implement your authentication pattern.

If Application A supports advanced authentication mechanisms such as OAuth, you can tie into them as well for similar results.

If it does neither, you are out of luck. There is no such thing as a universal standard for the exchange of authentication state.

Comment: Application A being a standalone app it does not use OAuth type authentication. I was more wondering whether it would be good idea to go on trust between the applications. App B can detect, App A has authenticated. While App B cannot carry the authentication details, it can trust the App A has done the needful. Thus B tells C, of details of user of A, but uses a agreed static mechanism for authentication. Idea is that user does not have to create another login for B/C

Comment: Wether this is a valid idea depends on how sure you can be that App A has authenticated. My gut tells me that you are creating some massive attack surface as tricking App B to believe App A has authenticated will be orders of magnitude easier than breaking the actual authentication mechanism. Furthermore, if you can't detect any authentication details, you won't be able to extract a userID, thus severely limiting what functionality App B and App C can provide. My recommendation is to keep authentication separate and/or with with the developers of App A on a joint solution.